# My DNN model to compare MNIST dataset using tensorflow not making progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am doing exercise of DNN chapter from "Hands on machine learning using scikit and tensorflow" book. Below are the steps I am taking

**Steps**

- Generate new data set from MNIST such that each row has two images and its label is 1 if the images represent same digit else 0. 50% rows are of same digit and other 50% are of different digits
- create 2 DNNs dnn1 and dnn2 with 5 hidden layers and not output layer. Each DNN takes one image as input
- Join output of dnn1 and dnn2 and feed it to a layer with 10 neurons
- add last layer with single layer

Here is the link of [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16dR2ZL3BkF6EOXWcRo7R9ltZ6oUhqpJx#scrollTo=Okxup-QSOVyG&uniqifier=4) where I implemented it. It is not making any progress when training. But the solution provided by book is working, here is the [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lMNYU4KD9U3t_X15ZOaiB_ZEhjl2XVPA) link. My implementation and the books implementation is slightly different but they are similar with same steps. I have spent two days trying to figure out what is different but I am not able to find it.

May be I have done a silly mistake, It would be great help to me if someone can point me what it is. I am new to tensorflow, someone with experience in it may easily see it.

[My implementation in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16dR2ZL3BkF6EOXWcRo7R9ltZ6oUhqpJx#scrollTo=Okxup-QSOVyG&uniqifier=4)
[Books solution in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lMNYU4KD9U3t_X15ZOaiB_ZEhjl2XVPA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you normalized your data anywhere. The book solution does this right at the beginning:

```
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
```

Comment: Ya, thats it, I am feeling silly to miss such obvious things. Thanks very much you saved my day